# JQuery onkey up function in text area

Tags: jquery, html

I have a field in my HTML, and I want to check its size and value against certain validation rules.
Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#id_title').keyup(function() {
        data = $(this).val();    
        if (data == "    ") {
            $('#output').text("The title can not be spaces");
            $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            if (data.length < 5) {
                $('#output').text("The title can not be shorter than 5 characters");
                $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);   
            } else {
                if (data.length > 30) {
                    $('#output').text("The title can not exceed 30 characters");
                    $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }
        }
        data = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

The thing is, when it gets into any of the if blocks, it keeps stuck even if the user completed the info properly.

Comment: when you start typing the title is less than 5 characters, and your #SubmitAction will be disabled from then on...nothing in your code will change it back to enabled

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` is a property, for modifying properties you should use `prop` method instead of `attr`. Instead of using empty characters, you can use jQuery `$.trim` utility function and check the length of the value.

```
$('#id_title').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value), 
        error = '';

    if ( val.length === 0 ) {
       error = "The title can not be empty");
    } else if ( val.length < 5 || val.length > 30 ) {
       error = "The title can not be shorter than 5 characters and exceed 30 characters";
    }

    $('#output').text(error);
    $('#SubmitAction').prop("disabled", error.length);
});
```

Note that validating text inputs on keyup is not user-friendly, user enters a character and on the first `keyup` event you are showing an error . I would suggest using `blur` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the input field again enable after it was disabled for any if functions

```
$(function(){
      $('#id_title').keyup(function(){
        var data = $(this).val();    
        if( data == "    "){
        $('#output').text("The title can not be spaces");
        $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
          if(data.length < 5){
          $('#output').text("The title can not be shorter than 5 characters");
          $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);   
          }
            else{
              if(data.length > 30){
              $('#output').text("The title can not exceed 30 characters");
              $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);
              } else $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", false);
            }


        }
        data = $(this).val();

    });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

in first use `var` for your variable, `var data = $(this).val();` to be local. and then you should set `disabled` to `false` when user completed the info properly something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#id_title').keyup(function(){
    data = $(this).val();
    if( data == "    "){
    $('#output').text("The title can not be spaces");
    $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
      if(data.length < 5){
      $('#output').text("The title can not be shorter than 5 characters");
      $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);   
      }
        else{
          if(data.length > 30){
          $('#output').text("The title can not exceed 30 characters");
          $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", true);
          }else{
               $('#SubmitAction').attr("disabled", false);
          }
        }


    }
    data = $(this).val();

});
  });
```